# CLIPS simple percentage defrule

Tags: expert-system, clips

At the end, when the program is supposed to print the percentage certainties, the program hangs. What might be wrong? It has to be the calculate-percentage rule, since when removed, the non-percentaged data is printed.

```
(defmodule PRINT-RESULTS (import MAIN ?ALL))

(defrule PRINT-RESULTS::calculate-percentages
?var <- (religion (name ?religion) (aspects $?aspects) (certainty ?certainty))
=>
(modify ?var (certainty =(*(/ ?certainty 700)100))))

(defrule PRINT-RESULTS::print-religion
?rel <- (religion (name ?religion) (aspects $?aspects) (certainty ?certainty))
=>
(retract ?rel)
(printout t crlf RELIGION:  "              "  
                ?religion crlf ASPECTS:   "              "  
                ?aspects crlf CERTAINTY:  "              "  
                ?certainty crlf))
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are being caught in an infinite loop.  When you modify a `deftemplate` instance, you are replacing the original with the modified instance, which in your situation will match `calculate-percentages` again and again. So you need to prevent this infinite loop of rule matches.

Since you are using modules, consider calculating your certainty in a module other than PRINT-RESULTS (I'll refer to the other module as UPDATE-CERTAINTY).  Then in the `then` part of your `calculate-percentages` rule, you can pop the UPDATE-CERTAINTY module to prevent the rule from matching the modified fact.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, you can use an additional slot in your facts to indicate whether the computation has been done on the fact (in this example the status slot):

```
(defrule PRINT-RESULTS::calculate-percentages
?var <- (religion (name ?religion) (status ~final) (aspects $?aspects) (certainty ?certainty))
=>
(modify ?var (status final) (certainty =(*(/ ?certainty 700)100))))
```